# 2nd order Boundary Value Problem numerical solution (vectors), trying to understand the algorithm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, runge-kutta-methods

I have a 2nd order BVP:

```
x''=-Q*x/r 
y''=-Q*y/r 
z''=-Q*z/r 
x(t0)=x0
y(t0)=y0 
z(t0)=z0
x(t1)=x0
y(t1)=y0
z(t1)=z0
r=x^2+y^2+z^2
Q-constant

Need to find x'(t0),y'(t0) and z'(t0)
```

For solution, I'm choosing the values `x'(t0)`,`y'(t0)` and `z'(t0)`, and calculate the values for `t1`. I don't know, how to "calibrate" this values, in case if calculated `x(t1)`,`y(t1)`,`z(t1)` are wrong.

I know how to implement Runge-Kutta, and read a lot about `Shooting method`, however I don't know how to change the `x'`,`y'`,`z'` (3 variables) each time to get the final result.

**UPDATE**

```
I use the Shooting method as follows:
y''-P(t)y=F(t) - the form of BVP
y(n+1)=C(n+1)*y(n+2)+D(n+1) 
C(n+1)=1/(2+P(n+1)*h^2-C(n))
D(n+1)=C(n+1)*(D(n)-F(n+1)*h^2)
```

The problem is, I don't know what are `P` and `F` in my case

Comment: Is it really $r=x^2+y^2+z^2$ or $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$?

Comment: And please give a source for the added algorithm. It seems to apply to the problem class of linear BVP, your BVP is non-linear.

Comment: @LutzL in your case in the equation should be r^2. I simplified. The source is on Russian language, but probably you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all a lot easier if you generalize a bunch. Given a second order BVP:

$$y''=f(t,y,y') \\
y(a)=y_a \\
y(b)=y_b$$

where $f$ is a given function and $y_a,y_b$ are given vectors. The idea is that you know how to solve the IVP:

$$y''=f(t,y,y') \\
y(a)=y_a \\
y'(a)=y'_a.$$

Therefore, given a value of $y'_a$, you can simulate the IVP (using whatever IVP method you like) and obtain $y(b)$. Let's use $F$ to refer to the mapping $y'_a \mapsto y(b)$; then you just want to solve the equation $F(x)=y_b$ for the vector $x$, which is just a nonlinear system of equations. There are lots of methods out there for nonlinear systems. The only catch here is that the evaluation of $F$ must be treated as a "black box": there is no hope of having an explicit Jacobian of $F$ for general $f$. Still, such methods exist.

This is called the shooting method and it is the simplest method for ODE BVPs. There are faster and more robust methods out there employing different techniques like collocation methods and such.

Comment: My question is, how to use the Shooting method? I know what to use, I don't know how :) Edited my question to make it more exact

Comment: About the system of equations F(x)=Yb: is F(x) still a differential equation, or has another form?

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios It's a bit misleading to think of $F$ as a differential equation. It's now a nonlinear function that takes a vector (the velocity at time $a$) and gives back a vector (the position at time $b$). You happen to compute it by running an IVP solver, but you should forget that when implementing your nonlinear system solver. As I said in my answer, your IVP solver should be a black box to your nonlinear system solver.

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios Also your problem is not of the form you suggested in your edit anyway.

Comment: Ok, I 'm running an IVP solver for the vector of velocity, and compare with position. What if the result is wrong? How should I change the velocity vector to continue the iterations?

Comment: @SonyaSeyrios As I said, you use any nonlinear system solver that you can implement. A "black box" way (contrary to LutzL's suggestion which exploits properties of your particular ODE) is to use a quasi-Newton method, such as BFGS (applied to $\| F(x) - y_b \|^2$, probably). This is an analogue of the secant method in the 1D case. Or you could use a quasi-gradient descent method.

Comment: Could you describe one of that methods, in case of my problem? That's what I'm exactly asking for

Answer (score 0):

This is a boundary value problem. No need to supply derivative numbers as initial values. The number of boundary conditions is adequate and correct. Works in all ODE solvers directly. It has a classical closed form solution.

In numerical shoot through, employing sliders for  tuning each assumed  initial derivative is helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

In the ODE system $y''=f(\|y\|)y$ the first derivative $U=\frac{∂y}{∂y'_a}$ satisfies the differential equation
$$
U''=f(\|y\|)U+\frac{f'(\|y\|)}{\|y\|^2}yy^TU
$$
with $U(a)=0$, $U'(a)=I$. Solving the augmented 
\begin{align}
y''&=f(\|y\|)y,&&y(a)=y_a,\, y'(a)=x\\
U''&=f(\|y\|)U+\frac{f'(\|y\|)}{\|y\|^2}yy^TU,&&U(a)=0,\, U'(a)=I
\end{align}
system with an ODE -IVP solver will the not only provide the approximation $F(x)=y(b)$, but also the to the same order approximated Jacobian $F'(x)=U(b)$. Then you can apply Newton's method or any more global method based on first order informations.

Comment: I can solve the IVP problem. The problem is in implementing a method for finding the correct result for y'(t0), in case when y(t0) and y(t1) are known

Comment: The idea is then to apply the Newton method to the problem $0=F(y'_a)-y_b$ using the iteration $x_+=x-U^{-1}(F(x)-y_b)$.